# Change datatype of a column that strictly only holds year in the format yyyy

Tags: python, pandas

```
df.assign(Year=pd.to_datetime(df.Year, format='%Y')).set_index('Year')
```

Consider the df['Year'] has n rows with data listed in YYYY format. How can I change this to date-time format without adding month and day, the above code converts YYYY to 2015-01-01.

Comment: datetime format - without adding month/day - is impossible. datetime consists of a *date* and a *time*. A year is not a date. Technically, this converts it to something like `2015-01-01 00:00:00.000`, but the time is hidden by default in such situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for a [`Period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Period.html):

```
df.assign(year=pd.to_datetime(df['Year'],format='%Y').dt.to_period('Y')).set_index('year')
```

Or with [`PeriodIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.html):

```
df.assign(year=pd.PeriodIndex(df['Year'], freq='Y')).set_index('year')
```

Comment: This is unrelated but to able to resample it required a unique index but the index has repeating values and cannot be dropped since it is valuable information. Any suggestions how to deal with that ?

Comment: How would you like to resample? For clarity I suggest that you open a new question with a specific example.

Comment: I will make a new question. But just to respond here, umm Id like to resample yearly as the data points were collected each year.

Answer (score 1):

extract the year using dt

```
# Year with capital Y is column in DF
# year with small letter y is a calculated year and is index

df=df.assign(year=pd.to_datetime(df['Year'],format='%Y').dt.year).set_index('year')
```

```
        Year    height
year        
2014    2014    175
2014    2014    180
2014    2014    160
```

Comment: Yes, but the index now is int64 and I still want that to remain a DatetimeIndex  in the same YYYY format.

Comment: you expecting just a year without month and day to be datetime type? how will that be a date without month and day. So, either those be defaulted at 01-01, or you'll have just the year. Besides, if not 01-01 what month and year you like year to be associated with?

Comment: I need the df for pandas resampling and rolling averages and those are not possible without the index being of type date. Any suggestions considering I only have yearly data.